# How to do permutation in polynomial time?

Tags: permutation

I have a problem in which it asks to use permutation of letter and relations. i.e: n1,n2,n3 and (=,>).

I know the recursive way to do permutation with letters {(n1,n2,n3),(n1,n3,n2),.....} - In the problem above I want to insert relations either = or <. So it will be like :

```
{(n1=n2=n3),(n1=n2<n3),(n1<n2=n3),(n1<n2<n3),(n2<n1=n3),(n2<n1<n3),(n2<n3<n1),(n‌​2=n3<n1),(n3<n1<n2),(n3<n2<n1)}
```

The question is how to print all possible permutations ,this should be in a polynomial time.

I thought maybe using Dynamic programming can reduce time complexity ,but couldn't figure it out.

Any helps is much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Can you give some examples so we're clear about your problem? Also, what specifically have you tried? Did you manage to figure it out without the polynomial time constraint, and need to improve, or are you just lost?

Comment: I know the recursive way to do permutation with letters {(n1,n2,n3),(n1,n3,n2),.....} - In the problem above I want to insert relations either = or <. So it will be like {(n1=n2=n3),(n1=n2<n3),(n1<n2=n3),(n1<n2<n3),(n2<n1=n3),(n2<n1<n3),(n2<n3<n1),(n2=n3<n1),(n3<n1<n2),(n3<n2<n1)}

Comment: The right way to add this info is by editing your question (you can then also format it, so that it's not all in one line). Do you want to know the number of combinations, or enumerate them? That changes the problem drastically. Also, you should clarify that "=" and "<" are just symbols for your concern; your question reads as if you want/need to compare the elements, but it doesn't seem like that from your comment.

Comment: Thanks Silly Freak. I updated the post . I want to find number of combinations.

Comment: your original question said "find # of permutation", your comment says "find number of combinations", but now you edited the question to say "print all possible permutations"... I'm confused! I don't want to annoy you, but questions on SO should be clear and well-defined, so that they have clear and well-defined answers that will be useful to future visitors.

Comment: Sorry for that , I corrected the question . In fact I want to know how to print all permutations ,not just print the number of possible options . If you have any idea or hint that may help me,please add it .. Thanks

Comment: ok, your question looks way better now! It looks a little like homework though (especially when you mention dynamic programming without a specific plan on how to use it...) so I want to stress my earlier requests: What specifically have you tried? Did you manage to figure it out without the polynomial time constraint?

Answer (score 0):

You can't print all permutations in polynomial time, because there is N! possible permutations, and printing something is an action by itself. And inserting symbols between letters multiplies that by another 2**(N-1). Both of these factors are non-polynomial.